# How to change PostgreSQL IP address for streaming replication

Tags: postgresql, replication

I have Postgres replication (master & slave).

The slave server has 2 local IP addresses (192.168.1.17 & 192.168.2.12). As far as I know the streaming replication worked fine with slave using 192.168.2.12. But somehow the slave could not connect to master because it required another IP:

> 2017-01-30 23:53:13.510 WIB >FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "192.168.1.17", user "user1", SSL off

I can put 192.168.1.17 in pg_hba.conf to work around this problem. I want to know if I did anything wrong to make the slave Postgres IP change? It was working just fine.

Comment: How is the connection specified in `recovery.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the question about PostgreSQL - this is about routing. Just route from 192.168.1.17 became as better than from 192.168.2.12